# wrong transformation of points in rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, rendering, transform

I am rendering a scene with a simple camera in opengl, this is rendering loop:

```
            while(hasFocus)
            {
                    UpdateFrame(GetElapsedTimeInSeconds());
                    RenderFrame();
                    SwapBuffers(g_hDC);
            }
```

what I want to do is to select some object in the scene but some transformations act weird.
before rendering the scene a ray went through the scene from view point of camera to mouse,near plane until it reaches far plane. I draw this ray to see whether I am doing the calculations right or not. as you see in the snapshot below the ray is coming from strange position and not from my camera's "eye".

[image]

I have my own camera class. this is my initialization:

```
     Camera myCam(0.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     gluPerspective(60,(g_windowWidth)/ (g_windowHeight), CAMERA_ZNEAR, CAMERA_ZFAR);
```

and some other initializations. 
in `RenderFrame`function I am doing my picking and rendering stuff:

```
     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glViewport( 0,0,g_windowHeight, g_windowHeight);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    myCam.setView();   // just set the view matrix with GL_MODELVIEW
    myCam.rotateLoc(-0.5, 0,1,0);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    Vector3* pointss = GetRayPoints();  // retrieve the two point for my Ray
    setIntersectionPoints(pointss[0],pointss[1]);
    RenderFloor();
    DrawSpheres();  // inside this I test hit of the ray created by points and the spheres
```

this is `GetRayPoints`:

```
   POINT mymouse;                        
GetCursorPos(&mymouse);               
Vector3 pointsOnLine[2];
double mvmatrix[16];
double projmatrix[16];
int viewport[4];
double dX, dY, dZ, dClickY,zz; 
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);   
//glGetDoublev (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvmatrix);
glGetDoublev (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);
dClickY = double (viewport[3] - mymouse.y); 
const GLfloat* mtrx = myCam.getViewMat();
mtrx = myCam.getViewMat();
gluUnProject ((double) mymouse.x, dClickY, 0.0,mtrx,projmatrix, viewport, &dX, &dY, &dZ);
pointsOnLine[0] = Vector3( (float) dX, (float) dY, (float) dZ );
gluUnProject ((double) mymouse.x, dClickY, 1.0,mtrx,projmatrix, viewport, &dX, &dY, &dZ);
pointsOnLine[1]  = Vector3( (float) dX, (float) dY, (float) dZ );
return pointsOnLine;
```

and inside `DrawSpheres` I am checking hit or miss by point-line intersection mathematics and it works well and actually I am selecting the spheres but not in the pixel under the mouse as you saw in snapshot. the problem is just the wrong transformation and therefore position of Ray !
any insight ? is this Ray in camera coordinates and I should bring it into world space by inverse of viewmatrix ?!

Comment: Why do you flip the y-coordinate? Does it work, if you remove that?

Comment: no, because Microsoft Windows returns mouse coordinates to your program with Y=0 at the top of the window

Comment: And so should your viewport. You could try to set the first point to the camera's position. This way the resulting line can only be a point on the screen. If it is not, the problem lies somewhere else.